# Get Filename from NSURLRequest Without Loading

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

When a link in a `UIWebView` is clicked, the delegate gets an `NSURLRequest`, from which I want the suggested filename.

**Getting the Suggested Filename**

I currently use the `NSURLRequest` to create an `NSURLConnection`. The `NSURLConnectionDelegate` receives a `NSURLResponse` object, which contains the `suggestedFilename`.

**Without Loading the URL**

Is there any way to get the `suggestedFilename` from the server without waiting for the entire `NSURLResponse` to be loaded?

Comment: I was pretty hopeful about this `func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willCacheResponse cachedResponse: NSCachedURLResponse)`, but it fires **after** the `didReceiveResponse`

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding what an `NSURLResponse` object is.  When the `didReceiveResponse` method is called, the OS has not received anything beyond the headers.  Thus, that response object does **not** contain the body of the response from the server.  It contains only the headers.

Inside the `NSURLResponse` object, you should be able to access the headers that the server sent.  Look at the `Content-Disposition` header.  You'll have to pull it apart yourself.

At that point, you can cancel the request if you don't want to receive the data.  With that said, the server will be sending data while you do that, so if you want to avoid receiving any of the data, change the request type from `GET` to `HEAD`.  (If you're doing this underneath a web view, you would do that by using a custom `NSURLProtocol`.  Such an exercise is beyond the scope of this question....)